# Cannot build Docker image using spotify plugin

Tags: docker, spring-boot, spotify

I have been using spotify plug-in to build docker images, but it suddenly stops working for some reason, and it spews out error complaining about exec failure on spotify plug-in

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.5:jar (default-jar) @ SimpleWebApp ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/test/opd_workspace/my_simple_webapp/target/SimpleWebApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ SimpleWebApp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.2.3:build (default-cli) @ SimpleWebApp ---
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Copying /home/test/opd_workspace/my_simple_webapp/target/SimpleWebApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -> /home/test/opd_workspace/my_simple_webapp/target/docker/SimpleWebApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Copying src/main/docker/Dockerfile -> /home/test/opd_workspace/my_simple_webapp/target/docker/Dockerfile
[INFO] Building image imgprefix/SimpleWebApp
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.282s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 01 19:42:14 EDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/340M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.2.3:build (default-cli) on project SimpleWebApp: Exception caught: Request error: POST unix://localhost:80/v1.12/build?t=imgprefix/SimpleWebApp: 500: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error -> [Help 1]
```

My pom.xml plug-in is very simple, and maven project build and package is ok

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: have you intentionally removed the value of ${docker.image.prefix}

Comment: yes, I didn't include it, but it is set as

Comment: Can you hardcode the image name and retry? I know there are few issues around image name when not set correctly in spotify.

Comment: I can build the image by command line, but cannot do a mvn package docker:build. I have tried a few different prefix, but neither seems to work.

Comment: did you try mvn:docker with a defined image name `<imageName>myimage</imageName>`?

Comment: I just did, replace with a hardcoded name, still same error :-(

Comment: check if docker remote api is enabled. try executing `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/json`

Comment: curl: option --unix-socket is unknown

Comment: Try it from inside the docker vm

Comment: I am sorry, I am not very familiar with docker. What do you mean by inside docker vm? You mean in the VM that is running docker? I tried on that.

Comment: how are u starting docker? are you using docker machine

Comment: No, I installed Docker on a Ubtuntu VM, and run command from the VM

Comment: unix socket option is only available on curl 7.40 and above. Try updating curl. This will not resolve anything but will help in debugging

Answer (score 2):

Following the line:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.2.3:build (default-cli) on project SimpleWebApp: Exception caught: Request error: POST unix://localhost:80/v1.12/build?t=imgprefix/SimpleWebApp: 500: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error -> [Help 1]
```

It seems you are using `UNIX` as operating system and `Docker` answers you an error 500.

I'm using `MACOS` and It works perfectly for me with the same configuration as yours but before I need to evaluation `Docker` environment variables in my terminal with:

```
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

Comment: Host does not exist: "default"

Comment: Try `docker-machine ls` and you will see the name of the host you should use

Answer (score 1):

Using that library you can't use respository names with uppercase. Only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed.

So change

> SimpleWebApp

to

> simple-web-app

or something similar.